# Reason for defining functions in the beginning of a file

Tags: python, memory

Is there any reason other than readability to define functions in the beginning of code rather than just before they are called the first time. Wouldn't it be better in terms of memory to wait with defining till used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You usually define your functions at the beginning of a script file that is self-contained.

This ensures that when the actual *script* executes (which is located at the end of your file) all symbols (i.e. functions and variables) are defined.